# Outlook 2010 inbox is spammed with meeting acceptances

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, meeting-request

A teammate at work sent out a meeting request to several people.  They all accepted.  However, one of those people's meeting acceptance notes keeps spamming  the creators Inbox.  The meeting acceptance came in probably more than 100 times.  They were deleted and then shortly after a hundred more or so came in.  This is in Outlook 2010.  This is such a weird problem and I'm not really sure where to begin looking.  Unfortunately I don't have access to the actual Exchange server either.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Speak to the people in charge of the Exchange Server; They're probably going to have to be the ones who deal with it, and it may be a sign of a larger server-side problem.