# Meeting request acceptance email sending repeatedly

Tags: mac, email, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, outlook-web-access

Have a user who is using Outlook 2010 on their Mac for office work and it's been continuously sending an automated email for accepting an invite to a calendar meeting for a couple of weeks now.

I have found a number of instances of this just by searching but the closest thing to a solution I have found are suggested workarounds involving using the OWA.

To anyone considering linking [Outlook 2010 inbox is spammed with meeting acceptances](https://superuser.com/questions/413875/outlook-2010-inbox-is-spammed-with-meeting-acceptances) **I** have access to the Exchange.

Comment: Have you tried getting them to delete and re-enter the meeting?

Comment: Currently being attempted